# SEO: Does Google recognize dynamically inserted text via Angular?

Tags: angularjs, search, seo

I've created an angular SPA that dynamically inserts text all over the place but more specifically it has a service that dynamically changes the title tag for each page. Is Google able to index this properly?

See ps101.com for it in action.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about SEO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find some information here:

- http://mono.software/2016/02/18/SEO-for-javascript-applications/
- http://searchengineland.com/can-now-trust-google-crawl-ajax-sites-235267#.Vq9umCaPP-Y.twitter

[@eywu](https://twitter.com/eywu) from twitter did also some tests on www.jscrawlability.com.
[As you can see](https://www.google.fr/search?q=site:jscrawlability.com&oq=site:jscrawlability.com&hl=en&gws_rd=cr&ei=7CUWV8aaGYfYafuSi9gJ), the site is not properly indexed on google.

I would recommend you [SEO4Ajax](https://www.seo4ajax.com/) to index reliably your website. You can test it, it's free for small sites.